# Python で複数の辞書型リストを一つに結合したい

Tags: python

共通のキーidがある２つの辞書型リストで、辞書内のidが共通のものは辞書をマージ
片方にキーが存在しないものは処理をせず、期待する値を求めたいです。

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'add': 'add'}, {'id': 3, 'add': 'add'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'name':'aaa'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc'}]
```

期待する値

```
c = [{'id': 1, 'name':'aaa', 'add': 'addd'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc', 'add': 'add'}]
```

Answer (score 5):

以下は `setdefault()` を使う方法です。

```
d = {}
for item in (a + b):
  d.setdefault(item['id'], {}).update(item)
c = list(d.values())

print(c)
=>
[{'id': 1, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'aaa'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'},
 {'id': 3, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'ccc'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

pythonのgroupbyと辞書のupdateを使う方法です。

```py
from itertools import groupby
a = [{'id': 1, 'add': 'add'}, {'id': 3, 'add': 'add'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'name':'aaa'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc'}]

ab = a+b
ab.sort(key=lambda x: x['id'])
c = []
for k, g in groupby(ab, key=lambda x: x['id']):
    d = dict()
    for i in g:
        d.update(i) 
    c.append(d)
```

実行結果

```
[{'id': 1, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'aaa'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'}, {'id': 3, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'ccc'}]
```

Comment: こっちは、キレイですね！

Answer (score 2):

もっとキレイなやり方があるような気がしますが、サンプルとしてこのようにできます：

```
import copy

a = [{'id': 1, 'add': 'add'}, {'id': 3, 'add': 'add'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'name':'aaa'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc'}]


# 簡易idでキーできるようにdictへ変換
a_dict = {d['id']: d for d in a}
b_dict  = {d['id']: d for d in b}

c = copy.copy(a_dict)

all_keys  = set(c.keys()).union(set(b_dict.keys()))
for entry_id in all_keys:
    if entry_id in c:
        c[entry_id].update(b_dict[entry_id])
    else:
        c[entry_id] = b_dict[entry_id]
```

出力：

> {1: {'id': 1, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'aaa'},
> 3: {'id': 3, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'ccc'},
> 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'}}

それがリストにしたいなら

```
c = list(c.values())
```

出力：

> [{'id': 1, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'aaa'},
> {'id': 3, 'add': 'add', 'name': 'ccc'},
> {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'}]